# react-native - Xcode 15 Cycle inside ...; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an issue while adding framework for iOS.

I am using:

- Xcode 15
- reaect-native 0.72.7

The framework I added:

- [ConPDS for iOS](https://support.conpds.com/support/solutions/articles/67000666945-ios)
- In Xcode 15 -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content -> ConPDS.framework -> Embed & Sign

After adding, I run build and there is an error:

> Cycle inside ...; building could produce unreliable results

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 15, I go to Build Phases and move "Embed Frameworks" below "Copy Bundle Resources"

Please take a look at the below image for more information.

[image]